# What vehicles are well-suited for each stage?

Tags: hill-climb-racing

In Hill Climb Racing we have several vehicles and several stages. 
Different vehicles have different performances on the same stage, and I'd like to know what are the best combinations to maximize distance in each stage.

Also, what is the best combination of a vehicle and a stage to get lots of coins?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Some hints for each stage, and my 3 best vehicles below.

As far as money, either take the fully upgraded Truck to highway and take your time with it (can get millions per run this way if you are careful/patient, but the runs are slow), or take something like Motocross Bike to the moon and just rack up the air/flips.

#### Countryside

Most vehicles can do ok here.  Once you hit 2000m, there are a couple of hills that are very tricky, and one in particular that is very hard to not break your neck when you land.

1. Dune Buggy 2223m
2. Monster Truck 2156m
3. Jeep 2154m

#### Xmas

The trees don't really get in the way here.  I don't have much fun with this stage, so I haven't put much time into it.  Gas becomes the limiting factor.

1. Tank 3073m
2. Dune Buggy 2590m
3. Truck 1921m

#### Desert

Traction is key for this one.

1. Monster Truck 3638m
2. Tank 3051m
3. Truck 2872m

#### Arctic

Again traction is the main concern.  The hill at around 2340m stops most vehicles that get that far.

1. Dune Buggy 3219m
2. Snow Mobile 2563m
3. Quad Bike 2431m

#### Highway

This one's all about gas.  The distance between gas cans goes up about 50m each time you get to one, so watch your distance and try to figure out when the next one is coming up so that you don't jump over it.  Any vehicle without a gas upgrade will need to hit every gas after about 1400m.

1. Kiddie Express 18028m
2. Truck 14678m
3. Super Diesel 4x4 9047m
4. Racecar 32037m. Requires nigh perfect runs

#### Cave

Slower or shorter vehicles do well here because they are easier to keep from flying over jumps.  Eventually traction and speed to get up some hills become an issue, at which point you have to get real good at letting off the gas early and cresting the hills.

1. Dune Buggy 2876m
2. Rally Car 2431m
3. Jeep 2369m

#### Moon

This one is just really hard to get distance on - the second one wheel gets off the ground you are starting to flip.  Tank does consistently well because of its tracks.

1. Tank 1253m
2. Monster Truck 1111m
3. Rally Car 1090m

#### Mars

A combination of cave and moon.  Timing when you let off the gas becomes even more critical than in cave.  Take your time.

1. Jeep 1586m
2. Tank 1562m
3. Quad Bike 1446m

#### Alien Planet

The slick surface means that very early in the level you need a running start for most hills.  If you jump off a hill and land on the up slope of another, you have to back down and start over.  Better to gently crest the hill, ride down the other side and pick up speed for the next.  There's a hill at around 1150m that stops most vehicles.

1. Snowmobile 2351m
2. Jeep 1313m
3. Race Car 1257m

#### Arctic Cave

Like a slicker version of cave.

1. Dune Buggy 1910m
2. Hovercraft 1235m
3. Snow Mobile 1159m

#### Forest

It takes power and traction to push through the trees.  I don't enjoy this one very much so I haven't put in much time. The Hippie Van is not affected by the trees, but it still does not seem as effective as the 3 below.

1. Tank 1727m
2. Dune Buggy 1602m
3. Monster Truck 1563m

#### Mountain

The Mountain stage works best with vehicles that are good at making short, steep climbs, and are resilient to flipping. The treads on the tank also handle the large number of sharp points very well, when other vehicles get stuck with a tire on either side of the point.

1. Tank 2114m
2. Dune Buggy 1884m
3. Hovercraft 1434m

#### Mudpool

Performance seems to diminish as you get muddy in this one, so try to jump as much mud as you can.  Traction up hills becomes the biggest issue.  The hovercraft will skim the surface of the liquid, which is handy.

1. Dune Buggy 2266m
2. Big Finger 2142m
3. Tank 2023m

#### Volcano

Jumping the fire becomes pretty important when gas gets scarce.  Again, the hovercraft will skim the surface of the liquid, which means you will never have extended fires.

1. Tank 2958m
2. Rally Car 2177m
3. Monster Truck 2071m

#### Beach

This one's actually really straightforward.  The dunes provide nice traction heading up the hills.

1. Truck 12338m
2. Tank 5694m
3. Dune Buggy 4357m

#### Roller Coaster

The key is a vehicle that can get up the very steep inclines - vehicles with down force like the Dragster, Race Car, or Rally Car are all effective.

1. Dragster 3991m
2. Race Car 2652m
3. Rally Car 1562m

---

I have not put as much time into the following tracks.

#### Night

The rolling hills and scarcity of gas make this track similar to Highway. However, traction is not as good.

1. Tank 4424m
2. Tractor 2877m
3. Monster Truck 2355m

#### Rooftops

The key to this stage is not to hit all the ramps with speed.  The very flat ones, like the first few wooden ramps, are safe, as are the dark ones at the edges of the rooftops.  Any other higher ramps are liable to land you in between rooftops if you hit them with speed.  Unfortunately you do not get lots of air time for falling down the holes!

1. Monster Truck 2763m
2. Jeep 2666m
3. Motocross Bike 2651m

#### Junkyard

There doesn't seem to be much of a trick to this one.  Another "traction and gas" track.

1. Tank 2746m
2. Super Diesel 4x4 2455m
3. ?

#### Construction

The swinging beams make this one tricky.  The best strategy is probably to travel slowly to see how the beam is supported and work from there.

1. Big Finger 1964m
2. Tank 1584m
3. Quad Bike 1564m

#### Rainbow

This is a tough course.  You just have to spend a good bit of time figuring out which jumps to take at which speeds.

1. Rally Car 2776m
2. Truck 1775m
3. Quad Bike 1507m

#### Haunted

This was a pretty boring course, I only went through it a couple of times.

1. Tank 4684m
2. Super Diesel 4x4 2319m
3. Big Finger 2316m

#### Northpole

Also pretty boring.  The presents can get annoying.  I imagine tank and truck would fare well, possibly also snow mobile.
Update: BF is good here. Earned 10m+ coins going from level 45 to 62 in one go.

1. Big Finger 16040m (level 64)
2. Dune Buggy 6291m
3. Sleigh 2108m

Comment: What about farming coins to get said upgrades? Stuff isn't exactly cheap and money isn't abundant.

Comment: @Rapitor As I mentioned at the top of my answer, taking the truck (or some other vehicle with upgraded gas capacity) out on highway, or some small flippy vehicle like the bike on Moon are the 2 best ways I've found.  One other way is just trying to get the best distance you can with each vehicle on each track.  Start with vehicles that you've already upgraded, and then use the money that you earn trying to break your own records to upgrade other vehicles.  Once they're fully upgraded, use them on each track, rinse, and repeat.

Comment: For the record, the answer talks out the poster's *"3 best vehicles"*, the recent edit by an anonymous user which added *"At forest if you use the Hippie Van, you drive right past all of the trees!"* to the Forest Section i believe should not have been approved as it only adds this but does not edit the list bellow in which it should have unless the poster reviews the addition and validates that it does not break away from the original meaning of their answer

Comment: If you go ahead and build up the VW van, it can easily best any other vehicle in both the forest and the north pole.  Go hippies!

Answer (score 9):

To farm money I take a fast vehicle, like the buggy, and The Moon stage, and keep doing jumps of 20000+ coins. Try to do as many flips as you can while in the air.

Answer (score 8):

Bike + moon = keep doing turns in mid air for profit
I personally like the army tank fully maxed for mountain. All the other stages are personal preference.

Answer (score 6):

- countryside - tank
- desert - tank or super diesel 4×4 (must be fully upgraded)
- arctic - snow mobile
- highway - kiddie express (must be fully upgraded) or super diesel 4×4 (must be fully upgraded and about 2,000,000 coins were yours)
- cave - rally car
- moon - tank
- mars - rally car
- alien planet - hovercraft
- arctic cave - snow mobile (be careful though)
- forest - truck
- mountain - tank or hovercraft.
- mudpool - tank
- volcano - tank
- beach - rally car or super diesel 4×4 (must be fully upgraded).
- roller coaster - rallycar or motorcross bike or race car.
- night- rally car
- rooftops - police car or hovercraft.

Comment: I did over 3k on dessert with monster truck and over 2k on arctic with it as well. I don't think tank is that good...