# Which stage is best for getting maximum coins?

Tags: hill-climb-racing

In Hill Climb Racing, I lack coins. So, in which stage would I be able to gain the most coins by doing tricks and collecting coins left on the stage?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/141745/43105

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always use the [Motocross Bike](http://hillclimbracing.wikia.com/wiki/Motocross_Bike) on the [moon](http://hillclimbracing.wikia.com/wiki/Moon) stage.

When fully upgraded the Motocross Bike spins very quickly (courtesy of the Mid-Air Control upgrade), and when combined with the low gravity of the moon you can get up to 20,000 coins each time you leave the ground.

The moon stage is also described as good for farming (coins) on the [wiki](http://hillclimbracing.wikia.com/wiki/Moon):

> Its main characteristic is low gravity. It is also very useful for farming as air times are usually 10000+.

[image]

[Image from the wiki](http://hillclimbracing.wikia.com/wiki/File:Back_Flip.jpg)

Comment: That would also be my recommendation to farm coins. I maxed all my vehicles with that stage.

Comment: I do use this but I just want to say that race car in the moon will be another alternative, and can even go further distances easily.

Comment: I've also used a fully upgraded tank successfully. It doesn't get me as much coins for back/forward flips, but it's much more stable, so on average, I end up dying less frequently, and thus, farther along than if I had used the bike. With the tank it's also easier to land on the gas cans along the path than with the bike.

Comment: Use the moon buggy! I got millions

Answer (score 4):

I haven't played in quite a while, but I always found the race car on the highway stage to be a pretty fast way to gather a lot of coins. Quickly reaching the high-value coins seemed to be a pretty efficient way of coin farming.

You may also want to look at the answers on [this previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128860/best-vehicle-for-each-stage-in-hill-climb-racing?rq=1) regarding the best vehicle on each stage, since distance directly corresponds to coins earned. (though it doesn't directly answer coins earned over time, which seems to be more along the lines of what you're looking for).

Answer (score 3):

Moonlander on Moon Level.

Right as you start the level just thrust straight up until you reach about 1/4 on Fuel Tank. Just release and fall and you'll end up with 35,000 to 50,000 points within about 20 seconds. Rinse, repeat. You'll run about 1 million points every 8-9 minutes.

Comment: I've got to try that!

Answer (score 2):

Diesel truck in highway can get you easily 1 million per-run (~9000m). I haven't tried yet but some people report 17000m with the kiddie express, it takes some 33 million to fully upgrade it though (and it's pretty lame before that).

Answer (score 2):

Kittie xpress Maxed Out on Highway level, 15-20 million coins per round or more.

Answer (score 1):

Go on the moon backwards with the jeep - you get around 300 coins for air time while going on with jeep and when you get in the air hold the break button and you can get up to 3500 coins.